# sklearn cross_val_score() returns NaN values when I use "r2" as scoring

Tags: scikit-learn, regression, nan, cross-validation

I am trying to use sklearn cross_val_score(). Following is the example I have tried:

```
# loocv evaluate random forest on the housing dataset
from numpy import mean
from numpy import std
from numpy import absolute
from pandas import read_csv
from sklearn.model_selection import LeaveOneOut
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor

# load dataset
url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jbrownlee/Datasets/master/housing.csv'
dataframe = read_csv(url, header=None)
data = dataframe.values
# split into inputs and outputs
X, y = data[:, :-1], data[:, -1]
print(X.shape, y.shape)

# create loocv procedure
cv = LeaveOneOut()
# create model
model = RandomForestRegressor(random_state=1)

# evaluate model
scores = cross_val_score(model, X, y, scoring='neg_mean_absolute_error', cv=cv, n_jobs=-1)
# force positive
scores = absolute(scores)
# report performance
print('MAE: %.3f (%.3f)' % (mean(scores), std(scores)))
```

The above code works fine without any problem. But, when I change `scoring` into `r2`, all values in `scores` will become `nan`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is using `LeaveOneOut()` in combination with `r2` as scoring function.  [`LeaveOneOut()`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.LeaveOneOut.html) will split the data in such a way that only one sample is used for testing and the remaining is used for training. And here comes the problem, when you compute [`r2`](http://from%20sklearn.metrics%20import%20r2_score) on the validation set using this formula:

[image]

the denominator becomes zero since `n=1` (only one sample to validate on) so `y_bar = y_i` since the mean equals the one number that you have, this results in `nan` which you observe. This is bound to happen if your `cv = No. of data points` as shown below:

```
# evaluate model
scores = cross_val_score(model, X[0:10], y[0:10], scoring='r2', cv=10, n_jobs=-1)
# force positive
scores = absolute(scores)
# report performance
print('MAE: %.3f (%.3f)' % (mean(scores), std(scores)))
MAE: nan (nan)
```

And now when I set some other value for `n` it works fine:

```
# evaluate model
scores = cross_val_score(model, X[0:10], y[0:10], scoring='r2', cv=3, n_jobs=-1)
# force positive
scores = absolute(scores)
# report performance
print('MAE: %.3f (%.3f)' % (mean(scores), std(scores)))
MAE: 0.662 (0.229)
```